# Retrieve combined records' fields values based on another field in the record using SQL

Tags: mysql, sql

I want to combine records' fields values (to be comma separated) based on another field in the record.
To get the issue better, kindly check the example below, I tried to simplify the scenario as much as possible

I've the following table, assume it is called 'My_Table'

```
+------+-------+
| Key  | Val   |
+------+-------+
| A    | 5     |
| B    | 8     |
| A    | 7     |
| C    | 4     |
| B    | 8     |
| B    | 9     |
| C    | 6     |
+------+-------+
```

I need a query to retrieve the following table

```
+-------+--------+
| Key   | Vals   |
+-------+--------+
| A     | 5,7    |
| B     | 8,9    |
| C     | 4,6    |
+-------+--------+
```

Kindly note that [B, 8] exists twice, I don't want the result to be

```
+-------+--------+
| Key   | Vals   |
+-------+--------+
| A     | 5,7    |
| B     | 8,8,9  |
| C     | 4,6    |
+-------+--------+
```

PS, I'm using MySql if it matters.

---

[UPDATE]
BTW, it's not a duplicate question, the extra piece of info is solving the duplication

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Group by the first column and use [GROUP_CONCAT()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to comma seperate the values

```
select `key`, group_concat(distinct val) as vals
from your_table
group by `key`
```

Comment: This doesn't solve the repetition of 8 in B

Comment: I updated the question perhaps it was the same time you answered it so you got an old version of the question. BTW, it works great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query

```
 SELECT `KEY`, GROUP_CONCAT(Val SEPARATOR ",") as vals
  from table group by `KEY`;
```

Comment: `key` is a [reserved word](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html) and needs to be escaped with backticks.